# NHibernate IsUpdateNecessary takes enormous amount of time

Tags: performance, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

My C# 3.5 application uses SQL Server 2008 R2, NHibernate and CastleProject ActiveRecord. The application imports emails to database along with their attachments. Saving of emails and attachments is performed by 50 emails in new session and transaction scope to make sure they are not stored in memory (there can be 100K of emails in some mailbox).

Initially emails are saved very quickly. However, closer to 20K emails performance degrades dramatically. Using dotTrace I got the following picture:

[image]

Obviously, when I save an attachment, NHibernate tries to see if it really should save it and probably compares with another attachments in the session. To do so, it compares them byte by byte what takes almost 500 seconds (for the snapshot on the picture) and 600M enumerator operations.

All this looks crazy, especially when I know for sure that SaveAndFlush indeed should save the attachment without any checks: I know for sure that it is new and should be saved.

However, I cannot figure out, how to instruct NHibernate to avoid this check (IsUpdateNecessary). Please advise.

P.S. I am not sure but it might appear that degradation of performance closer to 20K is not connected with having some older mails in memory: I noticed that in mailbox I am working with, larger emails are stored later than smaller so the problem may be only in attachments comparison.

**Update:**
Looks like I need something like StatelessSessionScope, but there is no documentation on it even at CastleProject site! If I do something like

```
using (TransactionScope txScope = new TransactionScope())
using (StatelessSessionScope scope = new StatelessSessionScope())
{
  mail.Save();
}
```

it fails with exception that Save is not supported by stateless session. I am supposed to insert objects into session, but I do not have any Session (only SessionScope, which adds up to SessionScope only single OpenSession method which accepts strange paramenters).

Comment: What I am extremely unhappy for is that looks like this dirty check is done byte by byte. This is the only explanation for 600M number. However, I am pretty sure, those attachments differ in first or second byte, so I would expect 1-2 comparisons per pairs of attachments, in total around 1500 comparisons per 50 emails, not 600m!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've found an easy solution: for my class Attachment, causing biggest performance penalty, I overridden the following method:

```
protected override int[] FindDirty(
    object id, 
    System.Collections.IDictionary previousState, 
    System.Collections.IDictionary currentState, NHibernate.Type.IType[] types)
  {
    return new int[0];
  }
```

Thus, dirty check always consider it dirty and does not do that crazy per-byte comparison.

Answer (score 1):

May be I missed it in that long text, but are you using stateless session for importing data? Using that prevents a lot of checks and also bypasses first level cache, thus using minimal resources.

Comment: I am using the following: using (new TransactionScope()) using (SessionScope scope = new SessionScope()) { DoDatabaseOperation(); } Forgive me my ignorance but I am not sure how to create stateless session through SessionScope.

Comment: Looks like I need StatelessSessionScope instead of SessionScope... will test now. Thanks, Vijay!

Comment: Unfortunately, this fails: Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.ActiveRecordException: Could not perform Save for Mail ---> Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.NotWrappedException: The called method is not supported.
ActiveRecord is currently running within a StatelessSessionScope. Stateless sessions are faster than normal sessions, but they do not support all methods and properties that a normal session allows.

Comment: I guess what else can help me is FlushMode.Always for the current session. However, I do not have a session, I have SessionScope and have no idea how to set that flush mode.

Comment: I use this in my code : var session = ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder().GetSessionFactory(typeof(ActiveRecordBase)).OpenStatelessSession()) to open the stateless session and then using session.Create(your entity object) to actually persist the entity.

Comment: If you are running into any troubles do ask me because I have been using Castle AR for last 5 years and that experience may be of some help to others too. But I am not saying I am a guru though :)